# How do I store a variable permanently in a Word 2010 document using VBA?

Tags: vba, variables, ms-word, word-2010

I know how to use variables in Word 2010 using VBA. However, they are all reset when the document in closed and reopened.

How do I store a variable permanently in a Word document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom document property instead. These are stored on the Word document permanently, and can be edited and retrieved using VBA.

To create a custom property, go to File > Properties > Advanced Properties (this will be in a slightly different place in older version of Word but will still be there somewhere...).

[image]

Go to the Custom tab from the advanced properties, and fill in the name of your custom document property, the field type (you can select text, date, number or a Yes/No flag, which should cover off most options), and a starting value - you have you include a starting value or the Add button will be greyed out. Click Add.

[image]

You now have a custom property in your document, and you can use VBA to manipulate and reference it.

To change the value of your property, use the following code:

```
Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(1).Value = "Your new value..."
```

Item(1) is set because this is reference the first custom document property in your document. If you have more than one custom property, you'll need to change the number to reference the correct property, or write some VBA that will reference the property by name.

To pass the property to a variable, use the following code:

```
strYourVariable = Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(1).Value
```

Comment: Note that these have a maximum character limit of 255 characters.

Answer (score 6):

This can be used:

```
Sub Test()
ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="PermanentVar", Value:=100
'ActiveDocument.Variables("PermanentVar").Delete
End Sub
```

Check if it is retained:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Msgbox ActiveDocument.Variables("PermanentVar")
End Sub
```

[Ref MS kb Link](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/306281)

[Ref SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759840/storing-arbitrary-meta-data-in-microsoft-word-document)